# Exclusion of inner classes in query for jQAssistant

Tags: java, neo4j, cypher, jqassistant

I would like to implement some naming conventions with the help of [jQAssistant](http://jqassistant.org). All classes implementing the `PropertyConverter` interface should have names ending with `Converter`. This rule does not apply to anonymous inner classes. Now I have two queries. This one returns all classes violating the naming rule:

```
MATCH   (t:Type)-[:IMPLEMENTS]->(i:Type) 
WHERE   i.fqn='PropertyConverter' And
NOT     t.name =~ '.*Converter'
RETURN  t.fqn
```

But this query also returns inner classes which have names like `ABC$1`. I can find these classes with the following query:

```
 MATCH  (t:Type)-[:IMPLEMENTS]->(i:Type)
 WHERE  i.fqn='org.apache.tamaya.PropertyConverter'
        AND NOT t.name =~ '.*Converter'
 WITH   t
 MATCH  (h:Type)-[:DECLARES]->(t)
 RETURN distinct t.fqn, h.fqn
```

But I was unable to combine both queries so that I will get only the results of the first query which are not contained in the second result set.

How can I combine both queries?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The best approach would be using the pre-defined concept to identify anonymous inner types ("java:AnonymousInnerType"). It comes with the Java plugin and would make your constraint look like this:

```
<constraint id="...">
  <requiresConcept refId="java:AnonymousInnerType" />
  <description>All classes implementing the PropertyConverter interface must have the suffix "Converter".</description>
  <cypher>
    MATCH 
      (t:Type)-[:IMPLEMENTS]->(i:Type)
    WHERE
      i.fqn='PropertyConverter'
      and not t:Anonymous:Inner
      and not t.name =~ '.*Converter'
    RETURN
      t.fqn
  </cypher>
</constraint>
```